# Using Libtorrent session with Twisted - Stuck on Checking resume data

Tags: twisted, libtorrent

I am trying to get libtorrent to work by starting a libtorrent session in Twisted.

I have created two [scripts](https://github.com/vandenheuvel/libtorrent-latency-benchmark/commit/2bfaf173952187956ae436494f95939a1e7fbbeb) to demonstrate the problem. When these scripts are ran, libtorrent status is stuck on `checking_resume_data` for both scripts. When the contents of the `main` functions are executed without Twisted, that is, on the non-reactor, default main thread, these scripts work properly (and the libtorrent status of the torrent is set to `downloading` and `seeding` respectively). The behavior is the same under python versions 2.7 and 3.5.

This issue is [confirmed](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/9044) by a Twisted developer.

I tried to attach the python debugger (`python -m pdb seeder.py`), but couldn't find anything abnormal.

Does anyone have any experience with this problem or know why it exists? Has someone found a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it sounds like you just need to attach a debugger and see what's going on. checking_resume_data is supposed to be a short-lived state, followed by either downloading or checking_files

Comment: @Arvid When attaching a debugger, the script do not get stuck on checking_resume_data. I am not sure what causes this. We have also opened a ticket with [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/9044).

Comment: you could try attaching the debugger after you get stuck